# Why would I need threads for implementing a 'named pipe based on shared memory'?

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, shared-memory

While trying to implement the `Named pipe` (e.g. two **independent** unrelated processes that are using the same shared memory) I keep reading that I'd to use `pthread_atfork` and `atexit`.

I'm fully agreeing with the use of mutexes and semaphores — using them we can decide when `process A` would read/write and when `process B` would read/write.

But for what reason would I want to use `pthread_atfork` and threads for that?

**EDIT:**

An example where not using semaphores would cost dearly :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <assert.h>

 // Simple busy-wait loop to throw off our timing.
 void busywait(void)
 {
     clock_t t1 = times(NULL);
     while (times(NULL) - t1 < 2);
 }


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     const char *message = "Hello World\n";
     int n = strlen(message) / 2;

     pid_t pid = fork();
     int i0 = (pid == 0) ? 0 : n;
     int i;

     for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         write(1, message + i0 + i, 1);
         busywait();
     }
 }
```

Comment: A 'named pipe' (aka FIFO) is not the same as two processes using shared memory'.  There is some serious confusion here.  Controlling access to shared memory is tricky, but handling a named pipe neither involves shared memory nor a need for program-level concurrency control (the o/s handles the issues automatically).  (If you mean 'we have to simulate a named pipe using shared memory', then say so.)

Comment: Pipes are _not_ the same as shared memory. A pipe is simply a one-way communications channel, you write on one end and read at the other. Therefore you don't need to use e.g. mutexes or semaphores unless you have two or more threads or processes writing to/reading from the same pipe.

Comment: OP's homework is to write library code with interfaces analogous to a pipe. It should have a read and write function that allow communication between processes or different threads in a process.

Comment: `pthread_atfork` is a mostly useless function (the recommended usage invokes undefined behavior, i.e. the standard for it is buggy) and I don't see how either it or `atexit` would be relevant to your homework assignment.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Sorry , but I don't understand why not to use semaphore/mutex ? If I have two processes that want to read/write from the same shared memory , it can cost dearly , wouldn't ? please see my edited post two minutes from now , with an example .

Comment: You still seem to mix pipes with shared memory, they are not the same thing. You can use both in the same program, but only shared memory needs to be protected, not pipes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: OP's homework assignment is not to mix using pipes and shared memory, but to implement the functional equivalent of pipes using shared memory and synchronization objects.

Comment: @R..: You're indeed correct , +1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly, your pipe-alike structure should be located in shared memory (e.g. obtained by `shm_open`) and contain the following members:

- One mutex controlling all access to the structure.
- One condition variable for signaling a waiting peer.
- A buffer of some fixed size.
- Two offsets into the buffer for the current read and write position.

The read function should basically obtain the mutex, then check whether there's data available for read, and if not, wait on the condition variable and loop rechecking for data. Once data is found, you'll need to signal the condition variable if the read made it possible to fit more data in the buffer to wake up a potentially-waiting writer. Copy the data read into a caller-provided buffer then unlock the mutex.

The write function should basically obtain the mutex, then check whethere there's space in the buffer left to write. If not, it should wait on the condition variable and loop rechecking for space available to write. Once space is found, it should copy the data into the buffer, signal the condition variable to wake any reader that might be waiting for data, and unlock the mutex.

Both the mutex and condition variable need to be created with the process-shared attribute it you'll be using the "pipe" for communication between processes (not just threads in the same process). You probably also need to think about whether you want to support multiple readers/writers and whether you need single-signal or broadcast-signal semantics for the condition variables. There are a lot of ways to optimize the behavior, but the above outline should give you a general starting point.

Comment: So basically you mean that I'd need to use POSIX shared memory ?

Comment: That would be my recommendation, but there are several ways to obtain shared memory, and any of them would work. If the processes are parent and child, you can just make a `mmap` with `MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS` before forking and use that. Otherwise, you still have sysv shared memory (the old nasty interface X uses) and `MAP_SHARED` `mmap` of files that can be used, and perhaps other options too.

Comment: R..: I'll tell what , first I'll try your suggestion for the next day and use POSIX . If I'd have any problem I'd post it , okay ? BTW , are you sure that the threads & pthread_atfork are not necessary here ?

Comment: I don't see any reason to create extra threads; the code for both reading and writing can already run perfectly well in whatever thread calls it (e.g. the main thread if your program only has one thread). I also don't see any way `pthread_atfork` could be related/useful to the problem.

Comment: Indeed explain .... I did what @R said , and until now almost everything is working as expected !

Answer (score 1):

Nobody has said that you have to use threads to implement the named pipe. But your library code *could* be used in projects that are threaded and hence you have you handle many special cases. As you probably know SysV IPC objects like shared memory segments are not automatically removed when their usage count drops to `0` unless they have been marked for destruction. This means that if a program use your code to create a pipe and then crash for whatever reason, the IPC objects from the pipe implementation will most likely remain, pollute the IPC namespace, and consume valuable system resources.

The two functions that you mention, `pthread_atfork()` and `atexit()` are used to register callbacks that get executed whenever certain things happen. `atexit()` registers code to be executed whenever a process is being terminated in a normal fashion (e.g. by calling `exit(3)` or by returning from `main()`). This allows you to catch cases where your pipes were not explicitly closed and do the necessary clean-up.

Besides exiting the process without closing your pipes, the program might also fork itself. This is also a special case that you must handle accordingly. `pthread_atfork()` is supposed to register three callbacks to be called at various points when doing a fork.

You should also probably handle certain OS signals that might otherwise end up uncatched which could terminate the program before the proper clean-up was performed.

As you can see, writing a library is much more involved than writing a program. When you are writing a program, you control (almost) all use cases. When you are writing a library, it might be used in many different scenarious and you should think of all of them and be prepared for all of them. You should think of correct usage and incorrect usage. You should think of things like clean-up and what system resources might linger if your library is not correctly used. And so on, and so on...